# Google Sheets: How to use IF, ROW and SUMIF in this specific case

Tags: excel, if-statement, google-sheets, formula, countif

I have a table with the following columns: Branch, Code, Quantity, Code, Quantity, Code, Quantity.

I need a formula that looks for a specific Branch and if the branch is correct summarize all the quantities of a certain code.

Chart A (Raw) Here, names can be found more than once and products will be in different order:

[Raw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cThsD.jpg)

Chart with formulas, here, branch and codes are only once:

[Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGDpQ.jpg)

So far I have this formula but I cannot get it to clasify between names:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFS(ROW(E:E)=1,"UNO",E:E="","",TRUE,(SUMIF(Raw!L:L,E:E,Raw!M:M)+SUMIF(Raw!P:P,E:E,Raw!Q:Q)+SUMIF(Raw!T:T,E:E,Raw!U:U)))
```

Comment: Use SUMIFS() as that will accept multiple criteria as you show you need.

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take this opportunity to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), produce a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13196995/daniel-h)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.